# Limit of $n$th root of exponentials

Tags: real-analysis, limits, exponential-function, limits-without-lhopital

I'm struggling with this problem:

$$\lim_{x\to \infty} \sqrt[x]{(7^x - 6^x + x^3)} = \text{?}$$

Although I've tried to apply the squeeze theorem, as:

$$\sqrt[x]{7^x - 6^x} \leq \sqrt[x]{7^x - 6^x + x^3} \leq \sqrt{7^x-6^x}(\sqrt[x]{x})^3 $$

I'm not sure if this is correct.

Comment: Informally (and hence just a comment), for very VERY large values of $x$, $7^x$ is dominant under the radical sign, and so the limit becomes $7^1$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$$\lim_{x\to \infty} \sqrt[x]{(7^x - 6^x + x^3)} = \lim_{x\to \infty} 7 \underbrace{\sqrt[x]{
1-\left( \frac6 7 \right)^x + \frac{x^3}{7^x} }}_{ \to 1} = 7$$

Comment: Makes sense now, I just overthought it. Thanks for all of you.

Comment: @Atti Glad to help you!

Answer (score 1):

Simply note that

$$\sqrt[x]{7^x - 6^x + x^3}=7\cdot\sqrt[x]{1 - \left(\frac67\right)^x + \frac{x^3}{7^x}}\to 7\cdot \left(1-0+0\right)^0=7$$

Comment: where did the square root come from?

Comment: ops I’ve loose the x, thanks!

Comment: OK, but $\to 7\cdot \sqrt[x]{1-0+0}$ is fishy

Comment: @zhw. in this way it is more clear that $\left(\frac67\right)^x \to0$ and $\frac{x^3}{7^x}\to 0$

Comment: When you take the limit the variable $x$ must disappear and thus the expression $7\sqrt[x] {1-0+0}$ in indeed fishy as pointed out by @zhw. You may perhaps write this as $\to 7(1-0+0)^{0}=7$ .

Comment: Yes of course! I really don’t know how what I was thinking about, Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

$$\lim_{x\rightarrow+\infty}\left(7^x-6^x+x^3\right)^{\frac{1}{x}}=7\lim_{x\rightarrow+\infty}\left(1-\left(\frac{6}{7}\right)^x+\frac{x^3}{7^x}\right)^{\frac{1}{x}}=7$$